# How to set java DayOfWeek values?

Tags: java, dayofweek

I want to create a function that gets an `enum` of `DayOfWeek` and then use this day's value to something else.

My problem is that I can't set (actually overriding) the returned values.

For example:

```
DayOfWeek.SUNDAY.getValue(); // return 7
```

I want to set `SUNDAY` to `0`, `MONDAY` to `1` and so on...
Is there any way doing it?

Comment: You want localized week day. Tell more about what you really want to do. What do you mean by *want to set SUNDAY to '0', MONDAY to '1'*? Are you using Java Time? Joda?

Comment: What about `DayOfWeek.SUNDAY.getValue() % 7` ?

Comment: @Tunaki - As you said, I want to a localized week by defining 'new' values for the week's days.
It's important for me that SUNDAY's value would be '0' and not '7'. this is going to serve me later on for some infrastructue I'm writing.

I do want my function to get the DayOfWeek enum, and than defining new days values.

Comment: But what do you _really_ want to do? And what are you using? Java Time? Joda? Setting SUNDAY to 0 doesn't mean anything. SUNDAY is SUNDAY.

Comment: @tunaki - I'm using java 'WeekFields', where the default based on the ISO-8601 standard that considers Monday to be the first day-of-week.
It mentioned there that you can adjust to the correct day-of-week, the problem I'm not sure how...

I know I can define my own enumeration, but I wanted using different way, with java built in Date pattern.

Comment: Isn't [`WeekFields.SUNDAY_START`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html#SUNDAY_START) what you're looking for then?

Answer (score 3):

## `java.time.DayOfWeek`

Java 8 and later has such an enum built-in, [`java.time.DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html).

Per the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard, the week is defined as Monday-Sunday, numbered 1-7.

```
int dayNumber = DayOfWeek.MONDAY.getValue() ;  // 1 = Monday, 7 = Sunday.
```

## Convert from ISO 8601 style to US style

If you want a week as commonly used in the United States, with Sunday being first, use math. Calculate modulo 7 then plus 1.

```
( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY.getValue() % 7 ) + 1
```

Like this:

```
System.out.println( ( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY.getValue() % 7 ) + 1 ) ;
System.out.println( ( DayOfWeek.MONDAY.getValue() % 7 ) + 1 ) ;
System.out.println( ( DayOfWeek.TUESDAY.getValue() % 7 ) + 1 ) ;
System.out.println( ( DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY.getValue() % 7 ) + 1 ) ;
System.out.println( ( DayOfWeek.THURSDAY.getValue() % 7 ) + 1 ) ;
System.out.println( ( DayOfWeek.FRIDAY.getValue() % 7 ) + 1 ) ;
System.out.println( ( DayOfWeek.SATURDAY.getValue() % 7 ) + 1 ) ;
```

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> 5
>
> 6
>
> 7

You question is contradictory and unclear, so I am not sure of your goal if you Sunday-Saturday being 0-6, then use above math but do not add one.

```
( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY.getValue() % 7 )  // Sunday = 0, Monday = 1 , … , Saturday = 6.
```

## `java.util.Calendar` constants

While I would never recommend using the legacy `Date`/`Calendar` classes, but for your information, the [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class defines a series of `int` constants (*not* an enum) for days of the week where [`Calendar.SUNDAY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#SUNDAY) is `1` and so on to [`Calendar.SATURDAY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#SATURDAY) is `7`.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Simply define your own enumeration with a member of type int, a constructor that assigns that int, and accessor:

```
public enum MyDayOfWeek {

  SUNDAY(0), MONDAY(1)....;
  private int id;
  MyDayOfWeek(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public int getId() { return id;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum DayOfWeek{
    SUNDAY(0),
    MONDAY(1),
    TUESDAY(2);
}

DayofWeek day = Status.SUNDAY; System.out.println(day.name());
```

try arranging your enum to the order. this might help you

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this:

```
public static int getDayOrderNumber(DayOfWeek dow)
{
    EnumMap<DayOfWeek, Integer> days = new EnumMap(DayOfWeek.class){{
        put(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY, 0);
        put(DayOfWeek.MONDAY, 1);
        ...
    }};
    return days.get(dow);
}
```

Only do some refactoring, initialize map in more appropriate place.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple method I wrote and I use it a lot:

```
public static int getDayOfWeekBySundayIs0(DayOfWeek day)
{
    if(day == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        // NOTE: getValue() is starting to count from 1, and not from 0
        return  day.getValue();
    }
}
```